Unknown widget ids are received from AppWidgetProvider on start up. OnDisabled update is never received
There are widget provider classes which extend AppWidgetProvider. The expectation is when any widget is added to Homescreen, it should get onEnabled callback. When the widget is removed from Homescreen it should get onDeleted call for the deleted widget. If there is no more active instance of the widget, it should get onDisabled call.
As per the current design, there can be a single instance of any widget in Homescreen.
The current behavior is - when we perform a factory restore, after reboot system starts up, new widget id is created for the configured widgets. Then the widget provider receives onEnabled update and onUpdate for the created id, as expected. When the widget is removed from Homescreen, the created widget id is deleted. As there is no more active instance for the widget, it receives onDisabled call.
Then if we reboot the system- once the Homescreen activity is created, new widget ids are created for the configured widgets. Then the onEnabled is received. Then onUpdate is received with some random ids, which were never created. Then onUpdate is received for the created id, also reecived the widget id list size is 1. When the widget is removed from Homescreen, the created id is deleted. But onDisabled is never received for the widget provider.
I assume that onDisabled is not received, because there are still active widget ids. I could not understand why we got some random widget ids in the beginning. This seems to be the main problem here. Why is it ok only during the first clean start after factory restore? Please note that the widget ids are not stored persistently. Could anyone please help to understand the issue here?
During the testing, 3 widgets are configured in Homescreen.
Log on clean start(Working scenario)-
creating new widget id 2
creating new widget id 3
creating new widget id 4
OnReceive: IntentAction is android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED
onEnabled
onUpdate: updateAppWidget for widgetID: 2

//remove the 1st widget
OnReceive: IntentAction is android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED
OnReceive: IntentAction is android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED

Log after reboot(Error scenario)-
creating new widget id 13
creating new widget id 14
creating new widget id 15

//unknown widget ids are received from AppWidgetProvider
onUpdate appWidgetIds size:2
onUpdate: updateAppWidget for widgetID: 9
onUpdate: updateAppWidget for widgetID: 8

//valid widget id is received
onUpdate appWidgetIds size:1
onUpdate: updateAppWidget for widgetID: 13

//remove the 1st widget
OnReceive: IntentAction is android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED
onDeleted appWidgetIds size:1

